# Unable to boot or install ubuntu on an Alienware M17x R3 laptop

Tags: hardware, installation

Neither can I install Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit nor can I just run the OS from a USB drive. It just shows a blank screen when I try to run it, and when I try to install it, the screen just flickers with rainbow colours.

I need some linux on it, what other distribution is known to work on these machines? I would be most comfortable with ubuntu if there is a workaround.

Comment: yayu - do you see anything at all when you boot from USB such as a purple screen with an icon at the bottom, before the black screen?

Comment: @fossfreedom yes, I see an option to either run ubuntu or install it. Selecting install gives the rainbow flicker screen, and selecting run gives a plain white screen after the purple ubuntu logo and then nothing happens.

Comment: bottom right should be some options you can choose - try "nomodeset" before choosing the option "try without installing" - does the desktop appear?

Comment: @fossfreedom That does not result in anything but a blank screen

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my HP tx2000, I downloaded the [**alternate installer**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download) and it worked. it should let you at least install ubuntu.

If you still get a black or flickering screen after the installation, try changing the boot options:

1. If the menu doesn't appear and boots straight into Ubuntu, restart and press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key until the menu appears.
2. Select the Ubuntu default kernel (usually the first option) and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key to edit.
3. Go to the end of the line that contains the kernel (starts with `linux/boot/vmlinuz`) by pressing <kbd>End</kbd>.
4. type `nomodeset`
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot

If that doesn't work, try using the option `acpi=off`.

Once you boot into Ubuntu, make sure you have internet connection. Ubuntu will detect and show you in a window the hardware that requires restricted (i.e not open source) drivers. It will then download and install them.

Answer (score -1):

Try using 11.10 of Ubuntu.  They seem to have fixed the issue with the video.  I'm not sure but I think the issue was related to the Hybrid SLI video mode that the Alienware has.  I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 as I write this on an M17x.  Good luck. :)

Comment: Rodrigo has some query posted as an answer addressed to you.

Comment: Kaius how did u manage to do that? I'trying but I cant get it to run... I've my post was deleted by a moderator and I understand that it not fit... so I've created a question post [Need help to install Ubuntu on Win7 Alienware M17xR3, intalling not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73033/need-help-to-install-ubuntu-on-win7-alienware-m17xr3-intalling-not-working) like u suggested... Thankz for the suggestion Yayu